# SonarQube create short lived branches from develop or feature

Tags: sonarqube, tfsbuild

So i have master (Main Branch) and develop as long lived branches, i want to derive a feature from develop, this means that the project will merge with develop and not master.

Currently i am passing the arguments:

```
sonar.branch.name=feature-abc
sonar.branch.target=develop
```

This gets ignored and i get "feature-abc from master", is there a way to force a branch to derive from a branch?

[image: sonarqube feature branch]

Comment: If SonarQube already knows about the branch then you can't change its target or type. Does this still happen if you delete the feature branch in SoanrQube and re-run the scan with the parameters you've provided?

Comment: @mc1arke unfortunately yes..

Comment: Can you confirm which scanner engine you're using and, if possible, the full command you're using to run the command?